# iOS 6 multiple UIWebViews: Javascript only runs in one

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6

An iOS 6 iPad app shows content in two UIWebViews. If both web views contain a jquery image rotator, only one will work at a time. Running < iOS 6, both work properly.

If the content of the non-animating webview is reloaded, it begins to work, and the other stops. Also, in the simulator ONLY, I can sometimes cause the stopped web view to start (and the other to stop) by clicking/dragging in it.

If one of the web views does NOT have javascript in it, the reloading of the stopped web view does not stop the functioning of the other.

My first thought was this was a focus issue, but the last bit seems to disprove that, and point so some kind of pollution between the two web views. The two rotators have the same selectors and same js scripts, but the js files are cached locally and are renamed uniquely to eliminate any stepping-on during the caching process.

I can't find anything in the iOS 6 release notes to describe a change in focus between different UIWebViews.

The web views are in an XIB, but but not siblings of the same parent UIView.

The desired behavior is to have neither of the web views go to sleep, obviously.

Comment: Not sure you will be in luck on this one. I hear extensive modifications were made to the Javascript engine in iOS 6. It was considered a success because, functionally, nobody noticed a difference. There is an, albeit obtuse, reference to work having been done here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_6
When on the page search for Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript works in multiple UIWebViews but it depends on the JavaScript. Using JQuery or other external JavaScript code can be a problem in case you link it with a href. You can solve these issues by copying the code of all external JavaScript libraries into your web page HTML. This is the reason why simple JavaScript works fine. Example:

[image: Screenshot of JavaScript in multiple web views]

This is a UITableView with a UIWebView in every UITableViewCell. In webViewDidFinishLoad i do `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.write('hey hallo'+new Date().getTime())"];`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making one WebView the size of your 3 webViews and the using 3 iFrames inside that 1 UIWebView that load each javascript enabled page?

Comment: Yes, but I have problem with positioning those pages, as they contain two halves of one big two-page image.

Comment: @pro_metedor hmm... Oh What if... Okay, so make your UIWebView twice as big then make the iFrame twice as big (adjust position using CSS) then stick the whole UIWebView in a UIScrollView and zoom to 0.5 (50%) so the UIWebView is back to it's normal size but the content is twice as small so it all fits. :) Boo-yah!

Comment: @pro_metedor CSS should position them just fine! Really :)

Comment: Well, the problem is that both iframes should not be scrollable but present whole the page (possibly scaled down or up depending on HTML rendering result).

I can't scale them into those iframe size. The size is given by half of ipad landscape mode (plus some padding) but I cannot see whole article on the page. I can't see any scaling parameters in CSS or HTML as IMHO they are not intended to do so.

Comment: @pro_metedor No, just make your UIWebView twice as big that way each iFrame is the size of your whole iPad, then put the whole (twice as big) UIWebView into a UIScrollView and then you can shrink it down!!! :)