# Multiple UIWebviews - javascript processing

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have a few questions for subject I am digging for some time:

Having two UIWebViews presented in one view, they load Javascript and are meant to process it. In actual state only one of them process Javascript, so my questions are:

1. Why only one of them process Javascript?
2. How can I force them to process Javascript? My goal is to make user see result of simultaneously processes Web Views.

I have sen that iOS allows only one UIWebView to have the focus so only one may process JS at a time. So my first solution was to switch focus (becomeFirstResponder) every 0.1 second between the views and it didn't work. I am trying to develop a new approach for that.

Comment: I am having the same problem, EvaluateJavascript is only working in 1 of my 2 (or more) UIWebViews. Have you had any luck figuring out how to work around this? I saw [a related post on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653926/ios-6-multiple-uiwebviews-javascript-only-runs-in-one) that seems to indicate that we are out of luck.